# (K)Ubuntu 12 does not detect my monitor connected via Display Port

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, xorg

I have one VGA and two Display Ports in my computer.
VGA monitor works well, but when connecting a second monitor to DP (with use of DVI -> DP adapter) I cannot make it working. The monitor connection is not visible.

No clue what I can do about it. Below I'm pasting information which may be useful.

## xrandr

```
VGA1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (0x47) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y     HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  18369
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB:  Full
        supported: Full         Limited 16:2
    audio:  auto
        supported: off          auto         on          
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x44
    Timestamp:  18369
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB:  Full
        supported: Full         Limited 16:2
    audio:  auto
        supported: off          auto         on          
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x45
    Timestamp:  18369
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB:  Full
        supported: Full         Limited 16:2
    audio:  auto
        supported: off          auto         on          
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x46
    Timestamp:  18369
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB:  Full
        supported: Full         Limited 16:2
    audio:  auto
        supported: off          auto         on
```

## lspci -v

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0577
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0577
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
        Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0577
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
        Memory at f7c20000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0577
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
        Memory at f7c3c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: mei
        Kernel modules: mei

00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point KT Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 02 [16550])
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0577
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
        I/O ports at f0e0 [size=8]
        Memory at f7c3a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: serial

00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 052c
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
        Memory at f7c00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
        Memory at f7c39000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        I/O ports at f080 [size=32]
        Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
        Kernel modules: e1000e

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0577
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at f7c38000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
        Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0577
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
        Memory at f7c30000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0577
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
        Memory at f7c37000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
        Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0577
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0577
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
        I/O ports at f0d0 [size=8]
        I/O ports at f0c0 [size=4]
        I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
        I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
        I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
        Memory at f7c36000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
        Capabilities: [b0] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0577
        Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
        Memory at f7c35000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
        Kernel modules: i2c-i801
```

Comment: I assume this is a desktop? What is your graphics card? Can it deal with multiple connected monitors? Does your system detect the DP screen if you don't connect the VGA (try booting with only the DP attached)?